# what to do to fetch initial data of components in _app.js page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ssg

I have a navigation bar that has a dynamic prop and data of this props should be fetched from API in `getStaticProps`. the navigation bar should be displayed in all pages of my website. so the best way to display the nav bar in all pages of my website is to put that in `_app.js` component. but I want to use `getStaticProps` method to fetch those data! and the problem is that `_app.js` doesnt have this feature. all my pages render statically. so if I use `getInitialProps` method in `_app.js` page, I lose automatic static optimization and I don't want it. in the other hand, I don't want to fetch the data on the client side. so what should i do in this situation? Whats your suggestion? **note: I searched a lot on the internet and I saw a lot of questions in Stack Overflow but I couldn't find exactly what I want.**

**UPDATE**
from the answers of this question and other questions, i think i have no way and i should choose between using a layout and `getInitialProps`. But i have an idea. I can fetch datas on the server for example each 60 seconds and then store the fetched datas in a json file. And then i can import that json file in my nav bar component and use the latest datas of nav bar components. Whats your mind about this idea? How can i implement this idea in next js? Thanks for help again.

Comment: The only way I can see to solve this is to actually include your Navbar or Layout component on each page and pass the data via `props` on all pages. Otherwise, you'd need to do what you want to avoid, which is fetch the data client-side.

Comment: But it is really bad! I should add getStaticProps to all pages file and i should get the datas from api in all of getStaticProps. And i should always wrap my pages component with a layer. Think im creating a website like amazon with next js. It is really bad that i should use a layer in all of my pages components. I dont know. Maby i have to wrap my pages component with a layer. Because fetching datas on client side has a delay to load the navigation items and its bad user experiance. Next js should really think about solving this problem.

Comment: simply use react server components

Comment: or maybe the new layout system of nextjs do the job for you. look at version 12.2 change logs

Comment: I searched about react server components but it is in alpha version. Is it ok to use it? And about the new layout system. I think it doesnt solve my problem because it is a normal react component and i can only fetch datas on client side. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use React context for the data that is required in other components. Populate it with data from inside a page component and use the data in other components thereafter.

Comment: Please don't use answers for chatting with the OP. Use them to answer the question. That's it. When you get enough rep, you'll be able to comment to ask for clarification. Using answers incorrectly gets you further away from that goal, as people downvote them, reducing your rep.

Comment: Extremely sorry was not aware about this as I am learning to use stackoverflow

Comment: Good place to start: the [help] :). In this case, [answer].

Comment: Are you sure? Because when we use getStaticProps or getServerSideProps to fetch something and use theme as props of our page component to create some elements, next js place the items in the actual html document and send it to the client side. But if we use client side data fetching, geting datas from api will take some times and the items wont be placed in the actual html source. I think your saying wrong.

Comment: @Saman You're correct. If you fetch the data inside a `useEffect` it will be retrieved on the client-side. It will not come as part of the server response.